# TextView underline phone number and hyperlink

Tags: android

I've written an app which contains a large textview for displaying notes.  Is it possible to have the textview highlight any phone numbers or hyperlinks without underlining the entire view?

Answer (score 61):

```
<TextView 
   ...
   android:autoLink="all"
/>
```

That's actually enough for you

Comment: Yeah, I keep forgetting about this. `Linkify` is good if you need more control, or only want to apply a conversion to part of the text.

Comment: I'm prompted to add the number to my contacts rather than dialing.  I'm using an Android 4.3 Emulator.  Is that the expected behavior vs. opening the dialer?

Comment: @BillMote late reply, but maybe someone would need it. It happens, because emulator doesn't have dealer app.

Comment: Is there a way to control the color of the links?

Comment: Never mind, I found it... android:textColorLink="yourcolorhere"

Answer (score 11):

You can use [`Linkify`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html) to turn phone numbers, URLs, and such into links that, when clicked on, launch appropriate apps (Dialer, Browser, etc.).

If you were fishing for just an underline effect, without the links, you can:

1. Mark up your text with HTML, particularly `<u>...</u>` for underlines
2. Run that through `Html.fromHtml()` to get a `Spannable` with your formatting in place
3. Feed that `Spannable` to your `TextView` via `setText()`

[Here is the list of HTML tags](http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html) supported by Android 2.1's edition of `Html.fromHtml()`. Note that this is not officially documented anywhere, so your mileage may vary.