# Hyperlink in Android

Tags: android, hyperlink, anchor

I have a question: How can I place a hyperlink WITHIN a text-block of normal text? I have some text and in the text I mention a URL and I want this URL to be in a different color, underlined and click-able.

I know hyperlinks in android can be placed with "Linkify"..
and i have referred  [android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html)  page

**Consider the same above paragraph with "android docs" i want to display in android.....**

Comment: @PM - I think you are looking for custom linkify for android, I hope this would may help you get what you want [http://android-geek.blogspot.com/2011/04/linkify-text-in-android.html](http://android-geek.blogspot.com/2011/04/linkify-text-in-android.html)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

@Fedor....
i have found to give links from  [API Demos](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/text/Link.html) .

this approach is finally be used for giving link in between text of paragraph.

```
     SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("text4: Click here 
                                                  to dial the phone.");

    ss.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC), 0, 6,
           Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    ss.setSpan(new URLSpan("tel:4155551212"), 13, 17,
           Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    TextView t4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
    t4.setText(ss);
    t4.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: Can we set a localized spannablestring?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at that [TextView underline phone number and hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026389/textview-underline-phone-number-and-hyperlink/3026883#3026883)

But I can see Linkify doesn't provide you the functionality you need. Not a problem, you can implement it manually. Just add ClickableSpans and handlre click. Code sample here http://www.orangeapple.org/?p=354.

Comment: ya this is correct to "Linkify" the WebURLs...

but "Android docs" should be as a link and when user click on this link then Tager URL should be fired , same as HTML Anchor tag

for eg.
<a href="target url"> Android Docs </a>

Comment: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/c25911cc80421e9c

even this one can also be used.....@Fedor

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but this is a problem I recently struggled with, and I found no StackOverflow answer that helped me. So after extensive experimentation, I found a solution and thought I would share it for posterity.

In your strings.xml, use HTML tags and the  markers:

```
<string name="example"><![CDATA[I know hyperlinks in android can be placed with "Linkify".. and i have referred <a href="http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html">android docs</a> page]]></string>
```

In your XML, make sure to NOT add any special attributes. Do NOT use android:autolink

In your Java code, you must use fromHtml, Linkify, and LinkMovementMethod. Make sure to call Linkify before LinkMovementMethod

```
exampleTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.example)));
Linkify.addLinks(exampleTextView, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
exampleTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Another caveat: if you are using these HTML links, where a link has display text that does not match the URL (Google and www.google.com), do NOT put raw URLs in the string. So:

```
<string name="example"><![CDATA[www.google.com I know hyperlinks in android can be placed with "Linkify".. and i have referred <a href="http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html">android docs</a> page]]></string>
```

Will turn "www.google.com" into a link, but will not turn "android docs" into a link.

This was very frustrating for me to figure out, as I tried many different combinations and followed many online examples, none of which worked until I found just the right magic combination described above. Hope it helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

[Use Spannable String](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html)

```
 private void setTermsAndTextToClickable(TextView tandcTextView, String termsAndCon, String wordTohyperLink, String termsAndConUrl){
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(termsAndCon)){
        tandcTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        return;
    }

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(termsAndCon) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(wordTohyperLink) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(termsAndConUrl)){
        SpannableString ssString = new SpannableString(termsAndCon);
        int startLoc = termsAndCon.indexOf(wordTohyperLink);
        int endLoc = termsAndCon.indexOf(wordTohyperLink) + wordTohyperLink.length();
        ssString.setSpan(new URLSpan(termsAndConUrl),startLoc,endLoc, 0);
        tandcTextView.setText(ssString);
        tandcTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

        ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View widget) {
                // We display a Toast. You could do anything you want here.
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        };
        ssString.setSpan(clickableSpan, startLoc, endLoc, 0);
    }else{
        tandcTextView.setText(termsAndCon);
    }

}
```