# Make a hyperlink textview in android

Tags: android, url, hyperlink, textview

I want to make a link for a textview text like [Google](http://www.google.com). Is there anyway to make link like this. (i.e) When clicking on the word Google it should open the appropriate link. Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116162/how-to-display-html-in-textview

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204036/hyperlink-in-android

Comment: just use  Linkify.addLinks(TextView, Linkify.ALL);

Answer (score 152, accepted):

Try this, and let me know what happen..

Using java code:

```
TextView textView =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setClickable(true);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
String text = "<a href='http://www.google.com'> Google </a>";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

From API level >= 24 onwards `Html.fromHtml(String source)` is deprecated instead use `fromHtml(String, int)`,

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));
```

Or in layout xml file, inside your TextView widget attributes

```
android:autoLink="web"
android:linksClickable="true"
```

Comment: i got the expected output. Thanks for ur answer

Comment: If the hyperlink text is present in strings.xml then none of the suggested answers are working. It works in very weird way. If I set the text directly in layout xml it works, but when I set the textview data in java code it doesn't work.

Comment: Just to mention that if you use the Java code you need to remove `android:autoLink="web"` from XML. I had both and it didn't work.

Comment: @Velu you must surround the string with `<![CDATA[string]>>` where string is your whole string text with a ulr. Was trying to fix this for an hour...

Answer (score 64):

use `android:autoLink="web"` in your TextView's xml. It should automatically convert urls click-able (if found in text)

Comment: Also include android:linksClickable="true"

Comment: @waqaslam in this case where we put a link.

Comment: @Garg's It's the text you set on textview that may contain hyperlinks

Answer (score 32):

All tested and working 100% 
Solution: `android:autoLink="web"` 
below is a complete example 
**Sample Layout** **Xml**

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtLostpassword"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:autoLink="email"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="20px"
        android:text="@string/lostpassword"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtLostpassword"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="20px"
        android:text="@string/defaultpassword"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
```

String in string.xml

```
<string name="lostpassword">If you lost your password please contact <a href="mailto:support@cleverfinger.com.au?Subject=Lost%20Password" target="_top">support@cleverfinger.com.au</a></string>

<string name="defaultpassword">User Guide <a href="http://www.cleverfinger.com.au/user-guide/">http://www.cleverfinger.com.au/user-guide/</a></string>
```

Comment: It doesn't work if i change this line >http://www.cleverfinger.com.au/user-guide/</a></string> for a diferent text like: Click here

Comment: this works only if text contains full URL like : www.something.com

Answer (score 7):

This can also be done by using the default property of **Textview**

```
android:autoLink="email"
```

Answer (score 5):

**Note :- Html.fromHtml is deprecated in Android N**

You need to do check and support `Android N` and higher versions of Android

```
                  //Set clickable true
                 tagHeading.setClickable(true);
                 
                  //Handlle click event
                  tagHeading.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                    tagHeading.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href='https://github.com/hiteshsahu'>https://github.com/hiteshsahu</a>", Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
                } else {
                    tagHeading.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href='https://github.com/hiteshsahu'>https://github.com/hiteshsahu</a>"));
                }
```

**Alternatively**

You can don't want to id programmatically add autoLink flag on TextView.

> android:autoLink="web"
>
> android:linksClickable="true"

This way You don't need to add `<a href='somelink'>` tags.

Which is a disadvantage, if you want to add `hyperlink` on a `text` you can't do it this way. eg you can't do something like this:-  [**hiteshsahu**][1]

```
           <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tag_info"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tag_ll"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:autoLink="web"
                android:linksClickable="true"
                android:text="https://github.com/hiteshsahu"
                android:textColor="@color/secondary_text" />
```

The result from both approach:-

https://github.com/hiteshsahu

Answer (score 1):

For Latest version of SDK `fromHtml` is deprecated
Use below line

```
String yourtext = "<a style='text-decoration:underline' href='http://www.sample.com'> Sample Website </a>";
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
        textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(yourtext, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
    } else {
        textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(yourtext));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have made a following extension function of a textview.

```
@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
fun TextView.makeHyperLink(url: String) {
    text = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        Html.fromHtml("<a href='${url}'>${text}</a>", Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT)
    } else {
        Html.fromHtml("<a href='${url}'>${text}</a>")
    }
    movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
    isClickable = true
}
```

and calling it like this

```
tvTos.makeHyperLink(tos_url)
```

You can also pass text as a parameter.