# I want text view as a clickable link

Tags: android, hyperlink, textview, clickable

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/link"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Forget password?"
    android:autoLink="all"
    android:linksClickable="true"
    android:textColor="@color/lgreen"
    android:textStyle="italic"
     />
```

Android is highlighting the links in the TextView, but they do not respond to clicks. Can someone tell me how can i do that as a clickable and move to another link.
i tried more times by seeing examples. but i can't. Can some one explain me clearly how to change text view as a clickable link.

Comment: Here is the link
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852184/android-textview-hyperlink

Answer (score 54, accepted):

All tested and working 100%
below is a complete example
Solution: `android:autoLink="web"`
Sample Xml:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtLostpassword"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:autoLink="email"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="20px"
    android:text="@string/lostpassword"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtLostpassword"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="20px"
    android:text="@string/defaultpassword"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
```

String in `string.xml`

```
<string name="lostpassword">If you lost your password please contact <a href="mailto:support@cleverfinger.com.au?Subject=Lost%20Password" target="_top">support@cleverfinger.com.au</a></string>

<string name="defaultpassword">User Guide <a href="http://www.cleverfinger.com.au/user-guide/">http://www.cleverfinger.com.au/user-guide/</a></string>
```

Comment: Any idea why the link isn't clickable?

Comment: wasted probably 1hour until i found this. Chat Ai and search engine trash.

Comment: android:clickable="true" to make it clickable

Answer (score 13):

You can add click listener to TextView and start websearch:

```
textView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
         Intent browser= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(PASTE_YOUR_URL_HERE));  
         startActivity(browser);  
    }

});
```

and xml looks like:

```
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:text="@string/link_string"  
    android:textSize="14dp"  
    android:autoLink="web" />
```

Answer (score 7):

In the string file put this code

```
<string name="link">'<a href="http://www.www.com" >ForGet Password</a>'</string>
```

and in the XML file

```
android:text="@string/link"
```

Comment: text view not clickable brother. what can i do now.

Comment: what exactly u want please explain once

Comment: already i done what u said above. but now also not clickable. I don't know where was the problem again.

Comment: notice the single quotes around the string. I didn't try that, but almost edited this answer and then saw those quotes. Other way is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7641177/826946

Answer (score 5):

this is the most easy and understandable code

```
TextView link = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hyper);
String linkText = "This is my website <a href='http://programondaspot.blogspot.com'>Programondaspot</a> .";
link.setText(Html.fromHtml(linkText));
link.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Check out this [post](http://programondaspot.blogspot.com/2015/09/place-hyperlink-to-website-in-textview.html)!

HAPPY CODING!

Answer (score 4):

In your `onCreate()` method put this code:

```
TextView clickableTextLink = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.your_textview_id); clickableTextLink.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

I tried a number of solutions. But this worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 2):

this is the EDITED answer

Hi you can try by replacing this in you layout.xml file

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="visit the site at www.google.com from here"
    android:autoLink="all"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:linksClickable="true"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

I have tried it and it will surely work. and treats "www.google.com" as web link

Comment: i added what u said above. but it shows error in the string like this Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - error: Apostrophe not preceded by \ (in ')
 - error: Found text "Forget Password?" where item tag is

Comment: for now as a quick solution try writing "<a href='http://www.google.com' >ForGet Password</a>" instead of R.string.link and forget the string.xml

Comment: Try this Edited answer

Comment: this is again changed text name only. i want that text as a clickable link. In my code while i click on the forget password means then it will move directly to the webpage as i mentioned it in the text background at string.xml file. Hope u understand.

Comment: then boss why you going for that headache keep one button with backgroung="#00000000" and on click of that button call the intent to load your URL in browser. try it out

Answer (score 1):

Just add onClick tag to your TextView which equals the defined function. Just as below

```
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/link"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  android:text="Forget password?"
  android:autoLink="all"
  android:linksClickable="true"
  android:textColor="@color/lgreen"
  android:textStyle="italic"
  android:onClick="callFunction"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is simple implementation tested up to Android N

```
    String termsText = "By registering, you are agree to our";
    String termsLink = " <a href=https://www.yourdomain.com/terms-conditions.html >Terms of Service</a>";
    String privacyLink = " and our <a href=https://www.yourdomain.com/privacy-policy.html >Privacy Policy</a>";
    String allText = termsText + termsLink + privacyLink;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_terms_conditions)).setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_terms_conditions)).setText(Html.fromHtml(allText, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
    } else {
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_terms_conditions)).setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_terms_conditions)).setText(Html.fromHtml(allText));
    }
```