# Android- share intent as text which will open app if present otherwise go to playstore

Tags: android, android-intent, text, share

I want to share a text in any messaging app as plain text. On clicking this text: the user will navigate to the application if present otherwise it will take it to play store.
I am new in android, Please help me out of this. Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17877595/i-want-text-view-as-a-clickable-link
Check this.

Comment: @ThusithaMalshan I want to make link on text sends in whatsup,facebook and other social media

Answer (score 0):

You can share the text, but the power to handle that is not in your hands,  since you don't have any authority over the third party application which handles the text.

Comment: Thanks!! but how other application like myntra, flipkart and amazon is doing

Answer (score 0):

You need to do like this on click of your text

```
final String appPackageName = "com..."; /*this is the package name you want to redirect application*/
                try {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Application is already insatlled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
                    finish();
                } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                    Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this, "Redirecting to your app on playstore", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName)));
                    finish();
                }
```