# Make a hyperlink in textview

Tags: android, textview

I was creating a chat application where each time I type some text and press send, I create a new `TextView` programmatically and add to my existing `LinearLayout` like this -

```
public void addTextView(LinearLayout view, String text) {
        TextView chatTextView = new TextView(getActivity());
        chatTextView.setLinksClickable(true);
        chatTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        chatTextView.setLayoutParams(lp);
       // chatTextView.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.ALL);
        chatTextView.setText("me: " + Html.fromHtml(text));
        view.addView(chatTextView);    
    }
```

As per [answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9852280/609782) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734270/how-do-i-make-links-in-a-textview-clickable) I added 
`chatTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());` to this `TextView` but still my link is not clickable. (Testing on an emulator, this code is in a fragment)

Text I am trying to add here is -

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">url</a>
```

Have tried -

1. autoLink = web (it will highlight direct urls (ie www.google.com) but not hyperlinks (ie href).
2. Linkify.WEB_URL

**EDIT**

I tested right now and found that `setMovementMethod` works fine with hyperlinks if textview is from xml layout, but if it is dynamic, it doesn't work.

Comment: did you try `android:autoLink="web"` in your TextView ??

Comment: Yes I have, it will only work for direct links, updated my question

Answer (score 1):

you can use this:

```
String text = "<font color=#ff0000><b><u>"+ "click here" +"</b></u></font>";
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
textview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

Intent internetIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                                        Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
internetIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.browser","com.android.browser.BrowserActivity"));
                                        internetIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                        context.startActivity(internetIntent);
                                    }
                                });
```

Comment: Did you get my question properly?

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
TextView textView =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setClickable(true);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
String text = "<a href='http://www.google.com'> Google </a>";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    mTextView.setClickable(true);
    final String text  = Html.fromHtml(getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.url)).toString();
    mTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    mTextView.setText(text);
```

string.xml

```
<string name="url"><a href='http://www.google.com'> Google </a></string>
```

this is working perfect for me, try it