# How to remove unwanted link from TextView android?

Tags: android, hyperlink, textview, autolink

I set auto link = web but it create unwanted link when `TextView` text has dot with any character like "i.want" it will create link for it have to prevent this 
I try to remove dot from string but then guanine link will not generated 
give some solution for it

**code**

> linktxt.setText(myObj.getpost());

post will get from api .

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
TextView textView =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setClickable(true);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
String text = "This is Neel.desai I want to navigate <a href='http://www.google.com'> Google </a>";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

See here for more help [Android: textview hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852184/android-textview-hyperlink)

Comment: i want auto link but problem it create unwanted link user write i.abc then it will crate i.abc as link how i privet this @tauqir

Comment: please give any string example for that then I will be able to help you better.

Comment: my string is "Neel.desai" now when is see this string "neel.desai" is displaying as link

Comment: Please try again. There is little modification in above code.

Comment: ya i add this, but when user add text it will not add <a> 
 user add directly google.com i not set static text

Comment: please update your question with the code that you have tried so far.