# android make links in a TextView clickable

Tags: android, hyperlink, onclick, textview

First, I'll start by saying I've visited this two:

[question 1 about this subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734270/how-do-i-make-links-in-a-textview-clickable), [question 2 about this subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9290651/make-a-hyperlink-textview-in-android)
and both have failed me.
Second, my app is based on a single map fragment, i don't know if that's an issue, but the TextView is part of an info window which is displayed over the map.

I have the following TextView in xml:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_link"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:linksClickable="true"
    android:autoLink="web" />
```

which I want to make into a link, I'm feeding  the text programatically, and can see the text as it is, but it is not clickable, or "hyper-link"ed.
The following is the part where I set up the TextView in my activity:

```
TextView tvLink = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_link);
// make the link clickable
tvLink.setClickable(true);
tvLink.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
String text = (String) urls.get(arg0.getTitle());
// Setting the link url
tvLink.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

I have also tried making the TextView have attribute of `android:onClick="openBrowser"` and have this class openBroweser:

```
public void openBrowser(View view){

        //Get url from tag
        String url = (String)view.getTag();

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);

        //pass the url to intent data
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));

        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

but it also didn't work. I might have made a mess while trying the different approached, but I did try to separate each try. and am confused and in need of an outside look.

EDIT 1 :
added the following:

1. My string in the res file (inside a string-array)

[Click here for more info about this location](http://www.rishonim.org.il/petach-tikva/Info/site_show.aspx?id=1026)

(which works here, so I assume it should be a legal link as needed)

2. My whole XML file as requested in comment

   ```
   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="vertical" >

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/tv_title"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:textStyle="bold"
           android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
           />

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/tv_info"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           />

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/tv_link"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
           android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
   </LinearLayout>

   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/iv_image"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:adjustViewBounds="true"
       android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
       android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
       />
   ```

Comment: I have added the full XML.
I have a string-array in my values\arrays folder and i get the text ok, just not as clickable (I have added an example for my <item> in this string array in the edit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do will not work because a Google Maps InfoWindow is not a live view.

In the documentation for [Custom Info Windows](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/infowindows#custom_info_windows) it states:

> The info window that is drawn is not a live view. The view is rendered
>   as an image (using View.draw(Canvas)) at the time it is returned. This
>   means that any subsequent changes to the view will not be reflected by
>   the info window on the map. To update the info window later (for
>   example, after an image has loaded), call showInfoWindow().
>   Furthermore, the info window will not respect any of the interactivity
>   typical for a normal view such as touch or gesture events. However you
>   can listen to a generic click event on the whole info window as
>   described in the section below.

and

> As a result, any listeners you set on the view are disregarded and you
>   cannot distinguish between click events on various parts of the view.

So the clicks on the individual tv_link TextView within the overall InfoWindow layout will not be processed.

You need to use the [OnInfoWindowClickListener](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/infowindows#info_window_events) to listen for clicks on an InfoWindow

Comment: Well, I guess I'll have to follow the guide and make my whole window as a link, instead of just the text.
Thanks, I have overlooked this.

Answer (score 1):

To begin with take out:

```
android:linksClickable="true"
android:autoLink="web"
```

Like this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_link"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
```

This is working for me with a hard coded url. I suspect the way you are formatting your url is not correct.

```
String text = (String) urls.get(arg0.getTitle());
```

I'm not sure what you are getting from this, if you are using an array of strings.

The two questions you have linked to both use this format:

```
String text = "<a href='http://www.google.com'> Google </a>";
<a href="some site">Link text</a>
```

You need to format your string resources like this:

```
<string name="txtCredits"><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></string>
```

I cannot see how your custom class openBrowser is fetching the string in the right format for you.

I suggest you log everything.

```
String text = (String) urls.get(arg0.getTitle());
 Log.i("url = ", text);
tvLink.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

Comment: I changed my XML according your guide, but my text is still not clickable.

Comment: I have tested as you suggested, now it is displayed as a hyper-link yet still isn't clickable sadly just underlined and blue.

Comment: did you manage to open a link on a TextView inside a info window in a map fragment? according to another answer here it is impossible to do so

Answer (score 0):

Use below which will do all your task

String str = holder.restContactInfoTV.getText().toString();

```
        int index = str.lastIndexOf(",");


        SpannableString snstr = new SpannableString(str);
        ClickableSpan Span = new ClickableSpan() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View textView) {

                try {
                    String mobile = CUrrentOrderChild
                            .getRestaurantMobileCO();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,
                            Uri.parse("tel:" + mobile));
                    startActivity(intent);
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.updateDrawState(ds);
                // ds.setColor(Color.RED);
                 //ds.setUnderlineText(true);
            }
        };
        snstr.setSpan(Span, index + 2, snstr.length(),
                Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        holder.restContactInfoTV.setText(snstr);
        holder.restContactInfoTV.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```