# How to use a href in strings.xml

Tags: java, android

**String in strings.xml**

```
<string name="lblAuthor1">Icon made by  <a href="https://www.flaticon.com/authors/smashicons">Smashicons</a> from
         <a href="https://www.flaticon.com">www.flaticon.com</a></string>
```

**In Activity**

```
TextView lblAuthor1 = findViewById(R.id.lblAuthor1);

lblAuthor1.setText(getText(R.string.lblAuthor1));
lblAuthor1.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235131/set-textview-text-from-html-formatted-string-resource-in-xml/18199543#18199543) answer i read that

> I should only use `<b>, <i> and <u>` as they are listed in the
>   documentation.

But for some reason, the `a href tag` works in my app, so i was wondering if this could cause any issues because the docs don't include that `a href` is supported when using it in strings.xml

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**

change your code like this

```
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
        lblAuthor1.setText(Html.fromHtml(getText(R.string.lblAuthor1), Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
    } else {
        lblAuthor1.setText(Html.fromHtml(getText(R.string.lblAuthor1)));
    }
```

instead of

```
lblAuthor1.setText(getText(R.string.lblAuthor1));
```

**Method 2**

Follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42831623/10239870) answer

Comment: Any idea why my code works even though docs say it's not supported?

Comment: as per documentation If you aren't applying to format, you can set TextView text directly by calling setText(java.lang.CharSequence). In some cases, however, you may want to create a styled text resource that is also used as a format string. Normally, this doesn't work because the format(String, Object...) and getString(int, Object...) methods strip all the style information from the string. The workaround to this is to write the HTML tags with escaped entities, which are then recovered with fromHtml(String),

Comment: try to add  <b>, <em> <big> like this html tag to your string this won't work without using Html.fromHtml(getText(R.string.lblAuthor1), Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)

Comment: And if i only want to use the href tag for links?

Comment: And thats false, <b> does work without using html.fromHtml as you can read in the answer in my post

Comment: I'm just confused why <a href works with getText even though the docs say only <b>, <i> and <u> are supported

Comment: did u added this attributes in your layout android:autoLink="web"

android:linksClickable="true"

Comment: yes but even when i remove them and still just use getText it works without using html.fromhtml

Answer (score 0):

android:autoLink="web";

set this on  your TextView in the layout xml.

or

replace '<' symbol with &lt ; and try