# Making a particular text of a TextView linkable in android

Tags: android, hyperlink, textview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hyperlink in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204036/hyperlink-in-android)

I want to make a link on a particular text of a Textview. How it is possible in android ?

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, its Possible. Use `Spannable String` with `Clickable Span.`
Refer this [link.](http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/android_textview_rich_text_spannablestring). This is a good example for `clickable Span`.

Comment: yes i got answer..thanks a lot..